# How to set another price (EUR) after current product price in Virtuemart 3.8.8

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, virtuemart, custom

In current VM shop we need to add EUR currency next to domestic price, calculated by specific conversion value.

I was hoping to do it with custom VM plugin, however I am having trouble finding detailed documentation for VM plugin development.

I was thinking of using `modifyPrice` or `plgVmOnDisplayProductFEVM3` but besides that I am stuck on how to utilize them.

Are there any detailed examples of these methods?